# Box centered on a monitor, but not on tablet

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS which works fine on a browser. However, when I look at it from tablet (it's going to be in a phonegapp application). The box is skewed to the right and down.

Here is is on the PC:

[image]

Here it is on the tablet:

[image]

**HTML: (it uses bootstrap)**

```
<div id="login" class="loading xpad">
    <div class="centrediv"><center><h2>Test</h2></center><br/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pincode">Username</label>
                        <input style="width:550px" ng-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pincode">Password</label>
                        <input style="width:550px" type="password" ng-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <a ng-click="doLogin()" style="width:550px" class="xpad btn btn-block btn-success">Login</a><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/* Transparent Overlay */

.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.centrediv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.xpad{
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the viewport tag in the head?

Comment: Yeh, i've tried with and without

Comment: I'd certainly leave it in, and set it to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`, and then try to adjust your CSS from there, possibly using media queries?

Comment: Isnt there a setting for phonegap for overall size? I only have done native work but with say an Ipad in the settings portion you can have the view shrink to fit the screen. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

I have always used margin-left and margin-right to center something.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Now I do mostly backend and am not really up to date on CSS, so there may be better ways. Hope its helps.

Comment: This is still the recommended and best method to center items on the screen.

Comment: Yes, it is, but horizontaly.

Comment: Which brings about the question of why this wouldn't work with vertical positioning. However in the CSS the top is already positioned. I would assume one could use different CSS for a smaller view but then again, not my specialty.

Answer (score 1):

-Try to put **relative** position:

```
.centrediv {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

-Then add prefixes on translate atribute and delete that **negative margin left**, it's definitely unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Add negative margin-left

```
.centrediv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hkqpvymj/1/)**

Comment: Where as that will bring it left, it's not really a solution - i want it in the middle regardless of the sizes

Comment: I've just tried it - but i don't have to try it to know putting -300px left on the box will move it to the left. So where as it will fix the problem on the tablet...at a certain resolution (it's still not centrered) it then breaks the pc version which is too far left

Comment: ?? So if you have 50% left of 600px..make the math... 600/2 . Have you see my demo?

Comment: margin-left:-300px will work but it mean you'd need to remove the transform. you'd also need a margin-top:-[half the height] using this approach. It would work, but isnt flexible

Comment: Finaly a reasonable comment. It was a solution...no mention that should be flexible. And the answer shouldn´t be negative. Is a solution flexible or not!